# How can integrate JWplayer mobile sdks with xamarin android and monotouch?

Tags: xamarin, jwplayer

Is there any jwplayer sdk available for both xamarin android and ios? Where can I find a tutorials of integrating jwplayer mobile sdks to xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWPlayer doesn't appear to directly support Xamarin.  However, you can access any native library from Xamarin by creating either an [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) or [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) Binding Library.

Comment: Thanks.. These links give me a new hope :)